# How to retry reactive WebClient call?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rxjs, reactive-programming

I am using WebClient to call a third party API with an access token that may expire. If the token is expired then the API will return 401 and I want to refresh that access token and replace the value in the header before retrying. The logs are showing that the headers are being updated and retried but still 401s are being thrown.

Here is the code:

```
    public Mono asyncCallApi(String url, HttpMethod httpMethod, Object requestBody, HttpHeaders httpHeaders, Class responseClass) {
        System.out.println("initial token : " + httpHeaders.toSingleValueMap().toString());

        //Keeps throwing 401... -> token is being updated in header during retries but still throws 401...
        RetrySpec is401RetrySpec = Retry.max(3).doBeforeRetry(
                        retrySignal -> {
                            String token = manager.refreshAuthorization().getAccessToken();
                            System.out.println("refreshed Token -> " + token);
                            httpHeaders.replace(Constants.AUTHORIZATION, Arrays.asList(token));
                        })
                .filter(throwable -> throwable instanceof UnauthorizedException)
                .onRetryExhaustedThrow((retryBackoffSpec, retrySignal) ->
                        new BusinessException("Max retry attempts reached"));

        //defer needed to update headers when retrying
        Mono response = Mono.defer(() -> webClient.method(httpMethod)
                .uri(url)
                .headers(headers -> {
                    headers.putAll(httpHeaders);
                    System.out.println("Headers being used in this call: " + httpHeaders.entrySet().toString());
                })
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(CustomBodyInserter.fromValue(requestBody))
                .retrieve()
                .onStatus(HttpStatus::is5xxServerError,
                        res -> {
                            res.bodyToMono(String.class)
                                    .subscribe(e -> log.error("Exception occurred: " + e));
                            return Mono.error(new RetryableException("Server error: " + res.rawStatusCode()));
                        })
                .onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError,
                        res -> {
                            res.bodyToMono(String.class)
                                    .subscribe(e -> log.error("Exception occurred: " + e));

                            System.out.println("Error status code that occurred is: " + res.rawStatusCode());

                            return (res.statusCode().equals(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)) ? Mono.error(new UnauthorizedException("Unauthorized exception occurred : retry with new access token"))
                                : Mono.error(new BusinessException("Exception occurred, no retries " + res.rawStatusCode()));
                        })
                .bodyToMono(responseClass))
                .retryWhen(is401RetrySpec)
                .retryWhen(Retry.backoff(maxAttempt, Duration.ofSeconds(backOffDelay))
                        .filter(throwable -> throwable instanceof RetryableException)
                        .onRetryExhaustedThrow((retryBackoffSpec, retrySignal) ->
                                new BusinessException("Max retry attempts reached")));

        return response;
    }
```

It is being retried 3 times and each time throws 401...
and here are some logs:

```
initial token : {providerId=a18943db-7236-4338-9e2f-76d05bd13d60, Authorization=Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjcrbjFzRU1GQ01TNDFZa28zVlllWEJ0Z2RBQ2M2enM3ZDloaCtDc2FGZ009IiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn0.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.XeG-WeGnoBiurE358Q8mFQnm93pWOyvYnIdHNHKdJy3tNsba5jI9meLxdsAfpoSaBv1easwEJ0xb_hi3bGqXLiMtb-vaJan1EDrgl8YrE3wBq_p1Dh3pXlh7Df67hhWml4smWGBv1xz93wgwwVCHUOGmgLe9UMQjy-BjIVXgz_de9tccbvIOGjgwFEX6fQ0M8EqtNCANw5PuvUbqijM0jOBKCl-Xkfmrh3sh7DTzbIasOx2QgGDqDUIAc8KwFgmBv8XZBGH7jY4ckXn3J0TWYfGK0xArrHJvRGZrfQHhoPVcNNCj2JZhRwX-9A9ov57dxraM2teUuiI2cqIkA9kEbwxyz, api-version=3.0}
Headers being used in this call: [providerId=[a18943db-7236-4338-9e2f-76d05bd13d60], Authorization=[Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjcrbjFzRU1GQ01TNDFZa28zVlllWEJ0Z2RBQ2M2enM3ZDloaCtDc2FGZ009IiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn0.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.XeG-WeGnoBiurE358Q8mFQnm93pWOyvYnIdHNHKdJy3tNsba5jI9meLxdsAfpoSaBv1easwEJ0xb_hi3bGqXLiMtb-vaJan1EDrgl8YrE3wBq_p1Dh3pXlh7Df67hhWml4smWGBv1xz93wgwwVCHUOGmgLe9UMQjy-BjIVXgz_de9tccbvIOGjgwFEX6fQ0M8EqtNCANw5PuvUbqijM0jOBKCl-Xkfmrh3sh7DTzbIasOx2QgGDqDUIAc8KwFgmBv8XZBGH7jY4ckXn3J0TWYfGK0xArrHJvRGZrfQHhoPVcNNCj2JZhRwX-9A9ov57dxraM2teUuiI2cqIkA9kEbwxyz], api-version=[3.0]]
2022-09-29 11:42:28.922 [aais-retail-fuel] [INFO ] 80184 [nio-8080-exec-2] [] tConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ae041a7e : Request sent: {site_Id_kind='OracleID', site_ids=[185479_2, 185479], categories=[media], start_date='2022-09-09T00:00:00', end_date='2022-09-24T23:59:59'}
2022-09-29 11:42:29.549 [aais-retail-fuel] [DEBUG] 80184 [r-http-kqueue-3] [] tConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ae041a7e : Request sent to : /reports/pop/requestsasync
2022-09-29 11:42:29.646 [aais-retail-fuel] [DEBUG] 80184 [r-http-kqueue-3] [] tConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ae041a7e : Response: POST{uri=/reports/pop/requestsasync, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0x7bc55544, L:/192.168.1.57:58864 - R:api.dxpromote-stg.dataservices.doverfs.com/52.146.61.101:443]}}
Error status code that occurred is: 401
refresh Authorization
2022-09-29 11:42:42.102 [aais-retail-fuel] [INFO ] 80184 [r-http-kqueue-3] [] c.a.e.e.manager.manager   : PartnerFlowManager getAuthorization method called.
2022-09-29 11:42:42.104 [aais-retail-fuel] [INFO ] 80184 [r-http-kqueue-3] [] tConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ae041a7e : Request sent: AuthRequest{clientId='clientid', secret='secretkey'}
2022-09-29 11:42:42.109 [aais-retail-fuel] [DEBUG] 80184 [r-http-kqueue-2] [] tConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ae041a7e : Request sent to : /appaccess/authorize
2022-09-29 11:42:42.226 [aais-retail-fuel] [DEBUG] 80184 [r-http-kqueue-2] [] tConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ae041a7e : Response: POST{uri=/appaccess/authorize, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0xf3f3707f, L:/192.168.1.57:58863 - R:api.dataservices-stg.doverfs.com/52.151.241.0:8496]}}
refreshed Token -> eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjcrbjFzRU1GQ01TNDFZa28zVlllWEJ0Z2RBQ2M2enM3ZDloaCtDc2FGZ009IiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn0.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.Yw2TTMo12ZV0ftde-nd9m-6y6kqmz1l_0MCDJwHadjVzB3B2lm_UmGz8KyawC-ENWq2oRqACOdfzNbjdK5od46BzQhWjtuYCxtnaW_pdybq6Xz8QYpdxCDg00E_XewU4SI2ptvgHMmGj7o0aLjm46xzK0azCL2ueMXvuC5BpUxHIxnIKwGXzQTRGPT-uuTdoK5zyGzymlyCPZegubhmUi_VFcb3axDrVcMAHL9_-pN1KDStFoBkwpBOxZHKSyfxd2e-GT8mLWAnXjPpyXfz0-5q89nEjCplqtykK3y_RK5piwLIEAVdIM1M2Mv3_BZi9hBiD5fhjS1YPSBZ-1SXNSw
Headers being used in this call: [providerId=[a18943db-7236-4338-9e2f-76d05bd13d60], Authorization=[eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjcrbjFzRU1GQ01TNDFZa28zVlllWEJ0Z2RBQ2M2enM3ZDloaCtDc2FGZ009IiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn0.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.Yw2TTMo12ZV0ftde-nd9m-6y6kqmz1l_0MCDJwHadjVzB3B2lm_UmGz8KyawC-ENWq2oRqACOdfzNbjdK5od46BzQhWjtuYCxtnaW_pdybq6Xz8QYpdxCDg00E_XewU4SI2ptvgHMmGj7o0aLjm46xzK0azCL2ueMXvuC5BpUxHIxnIKwGXzQTRGPT-uuTdoK5zyGzymlyCPZegubhmUi_VFcb3axDrVcMAHL9_-pN1KDStFoBkwpBOxZHKSyfxd2e-GT8mLWAnXjPpyXfz0-5q89nEjCplqtykK3y_RK5piwLIEAVdIM1M2Mv3_BZi9hBiD5fhjS1YPSBZ-1SXNSw], api-version=[3.0]]
2022-09-29 11:42:42.234 [aais-retail-fuel] [INFO ] 80184 [r-http-kqueue-3] [] tConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ae041a7e : Request sent: {site_Id_kind='OracleID', site_ids=[185479_2, 185479], categories=[media], start_date='2022-09-09T00:00:00', end_date='2022-09-24T23:59:59'}
2022-09-29 11:42:42.437 [aais-retail-fuel] [DEBUG] 80184 [r-http-kqueue-3] [] tConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ae041a7e : Request sent to : /reports/pop/requestsasync
2022-09-29 11:42:42.525 [aais-retail-fuel] [DEBUG] 80184 [r-http-kqueue-3] [] tConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ae041a7e : Response: POST{uri=/reports/pop/requestsasync, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0xd4e089aa, L:/192.168.1.57:58873 - R:api.dxpromote-stg.dataservices.doverfs.com/52.146.61.101:443]}}
Error status code that occurred is: 401
refresh Authorization
2022-09-29 11:43:10.493 [aais-retail-fuel] [INFO ] 80184 [r-http-kqueue-3] [] c.a.e.e.manager.manager   : PartnerFlowManager getAuthorization method called.
2022-09-29 11:43:10.495 [aais-retail-fuel] [INFO ] 80184 [r-http-kqueue-3] [] tConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ae041a7e : Request sent: AuthRequest{clientId='clientid', secret='secretkey'}
2022-09-29 11:43:10.497 [aais-retail-fuel] [DEBUG] 80184 [r-http-kqueue-2] [] tConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ae041a7e : Request sent to : /appaccess/authorize
2022-09-29 11:43:10.603 [aais-retail-fuel] [DEBUG] 80184 [r-http-kqueue-2] [] tConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ae041a7e : Response: POST{uri=/appaccess/authorize, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0xf3f3707f, L:/192.168.1.57:58863 - R:api.dataservices-stg.doverfs.com/52.151.241.0:8496]}}
refreshed Token -> eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjcrbjFzRU1GQ01TNDFZa28zVlllWEJ0Z2RBQ2M2enM3ZDloaCtDc2FGZ009IiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn0.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.CT_RLyYNZrKLwgIOdi7c8jUfdrifm-6gSycFTTupoIPI3uuWt3LiWJy-YTvdW3u9EgFEX17camBqXoa-i4XR6mk-DLnWj4VpS_0g4iCdrSdDXFJTFawSi45SFP3omTWIzkIgphGcPVNNzpId6pLd95zJBF8wjZHusa2AGd6vzWWRJPnXCXxT55IskatFDgmstEA2s5dNIp8hdcUS2YXbC5Wl1lXqEKB-HNUOvgHdU2hYudvX1zEtpgUEpvsujnS6HPXL7_Tu6vPHCb0DzJortl3Lr5SQfXgZK4Rp9W1LOHFpi68msRHFv7XwU-sy6nrosti2YFSpWM0RMnmGiY111Q
Headers being used in this call: [providerId=[a18943db-7236-4338-9e2f-76d05bd13d60], Authorization=[eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjcrbjFzRU1GQ01TNDFZa28zVlllWEJ0Z2RBQ2M2enM3ZDloaCtDc2FGZ009IiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn0.eyJzdWIiOiJBQlNDTyIsImFwcGxpY2F0aW9uTmFtZSI6IkFCU0NPIiwiYXBwbGljYXRpb25JZCI6IjkyMmMzNTFhLTU4ZDgtNDQ2YS1iMmUwLTQ1NzJiZmNlY2NkNSIsInByb2R1Y3QiOiIqIiwiYXV0aGVudGljYXRpb25UeXBlIjoiQXBwQWNjZXNzIiwiYXBwbGljYXRpb25DbGFpbXMiOlsiR2V0SGlzdG9yeVJlcG9ydHMiLCJHZXRQT1BSZXBvcnRzIiwiRG93bmxvYWRQb1BSZXBvcnQiLCJQb1BSZXBvcnRSZXF1ZXN0IiwiTWFuYWdlQWxsVXNlcnMiLCJTZXJ2aWNlIl0sInVzZXJHcm91cHMiOiIwNTNlZWVjNi1lYjg3LTRhZTUtYWY1My00ODkyZWM2YjM2ZjEiLCJuYmYiOjE2NjQ0NzY5OTEsImV4cCI6MTY2NDQ3ODc5MSwiaWF0IjoxNjY0NDc2OTkxLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2FwaS5kYXRhc2VydmljZXMtc3RnLmRvdmVyZnMuY29tOjg4NjMvdXNlcm1hbmFnZW1lbnQvc3NvL3NhbWwiLCJhdWQiOiJDZXJlcyJ9.CT_RLyYNZrKLwgIOdi7c8jUfdrifm-6gSycFTTupoIPI3uuWt3LiWJy-YTvdW3u9EgFEX17camBqXoa-i4XR6mk-DLnWj4VpS_0g4iCdrSdDXFJTFawSi45SFP3omTWIzkIgphGcPVNNzpId6pLd95zJBF8wjZHusa2AGd6vzWWRJPnXCXxT55IskatFDgmstEA2s5dNIp8hdcUS2YXbC5Wl1lXqEKB-HNUOvgHdU2hYudvX1zEtpgUEpvsujnS6HPXL7_Tu6vPHCb0DzJortl3Lr5SQfXgZK4Rp9W1LOHFpi68msRHFv7XwU-sy6nrosti2YFSpWM0RMnmGiY111Q], api-version=[3.0]]
2022-09-29 11:43:10.606 [aais-retail-fuel] [INFO ] 80184 [r-http-kqueue-3] [] tConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ae041a7e : Request sent: {site_Id_kind='OracleID', site_ids=[185479_2, 185479], categories=[media], start_date='2022-09-09T00:00:00', end_date='2022-09-24T23:59:59'}
2022-09-29 11:43:10.608 [aais-retail-fuel] [DEBUG] 80184 [r-http-kqueue-3] [] tConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ae041a7e : Request sent to : /reports/pop/requestsasync
2022-09-29 11:43:10.700 [aais-retail-fuel] [DEBUG] 80184 [r-http-kqueue-3] [] tConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ae041a7e : Response: POST{uri=/reports/pop/requestsasync, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0x7bc55544, L:/192.168.1.57:58864 - R:api.dxpromote-stg.dataservices.doverfs.com/52.146.61.101:443]}}
Error status code that occurred is: 401
refresh Authorization
2022-09-29 11:43:17.265 [aais-retail-fuel] [INFO ] 80184 [r-http-kqueue-3] [] c.a.e.e.manager.manager   : PartnerFlowManager getAuthorization method called.
2022-09-29 11:43:17.268 [aais-retail-fuel] [INFO ] 80184 [r-http-kqueue-3] [] tConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ae041a7e : Request sent: AuthRequest{clientId='clientid', secret='secretkey'}
2022-09-29 11:43:17.270 [aais-retail-fuel] [DEBUG] 80184 [r-http-kqueue-2] [] tConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ae041a7e : Request sent to : /appaccess/authorize
2022-09-29 11:43:17.408 [aais-retail-fuel] [DEBUG] 80184 [r-http-kqueue-2] [] tConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ae041a7e : Response: POST{uri=/appaccess/authorize, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0xf3f3707f, L:/192.168.1.57:58863 - R:api.dataservices-stg.doverfs.com/52.151.241.0:8496]}}
refreshed Token -> eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjcrbjFzRU1GQ01TNDFZa28zVlllWEJ0Z2RBQ2M2enM3ZDloaCtDc2FGZ009IiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn0.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.liQTawC41pSX_5FjR-nM1QSjPzxEbIXfGKAlVKECKbPiHK8SZP18o2yTc4f3jk2dCMRjqXcI_iUTHZaBYvfUDXj7SbBkTHM1pJKT9B-L3ugLiBsf5R_PF5t1V5fzMY1-OPgivaOHpcSigurx8jqfhe1yEQvJeUu75LW0vv3VE9vtMrRGlbobKf8ZGsTXaDuNPbVPcUuqTdHEXAaHT7l7GV3sr9UZfSGfwBo8REnxQqV-6VSQIQYLxhM-U6WMDsXzqzP3-2igPcu9Swp1cjh02WdqUR4ngJju3JGQUFilgMgSphcSAqmSnAexDovKj4fY9sSLxM1L-SOvG2GWWmo1Nw
Headers being used in this call: [providerId=[a18943db-7236-4338-9e2f-76d05bd13d60], Authorization=[eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjcrbjFzRU1GQ01TNDFZa28zVlllWEJ0Z2RBQ2M2enM3ZDloaCtDc2FGZ009IiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn0.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.liQTawC41pSX_5FjR-nM1QSjPzxEbIXfGKAlVKECKbPiHK8SZP18o2yTc4f3jk2dCMRjqXcI_iUTHZaBYvfUDXj7SbBkTHM1pJKT9B-L3ugLiBsf5R_PF5t1V5fzMY1-OPgivaOHpcSigurx8jqfhe1yEQvJeUu75LW0vv3VE9vtMrRGlbobKf8ZGsTXaDuNPbVPcUuqTdHEXAaHT7l7GV3sr9UZfSGfwBo8REnxQqV-6VSQIQYLxhM-U6WMDsXzqzP3-2igPcu9Swp1cjh02WdqUR4ngJju3JGQUFilgMgSphcSAqmSnAexDovKj4fY9sSLxM1L-SOvG2GWWmo1Nw], api-version=[3.0]]
2022-09-29 11:43:17.413 [aais-retail-fuel] [INFO ] 80184 [r-http-kqueue-3] [] tConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ae041a7e : Request sent: {site_Id_kind='OracleID', site_ids=[185479_2, 185479], categories=[media], start_date='2022-09-09T00:00:00', end_date='2022-09-24T23:59:59'}
2022-09-29 11:43:17.415 [aais-retail-fuel] [DEBUG] 80184 [r-http-kqueue-3] [] tConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ae041a7e : Request sent to : /reports/pop/requestsasync
2022-09-29 11:43:17.514 [aais-retail-fuel] [DEBUG] 80184 [r-http-kqueue-3] [] tConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ae041a7e : Response: POST{uri=/reports/pop/requestsasync, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0xd4e089aa, L:/192.168.1.57:58873 - R:api.dxpromote-stg.dataservices.doverfs.com/52.146.61.101:443]}}
Error status code that occurred is: 401
2022-09-29 11:47:53.660 [aais-retail-fuel] [INFO ] 80184 [nio-8080-exec-2] [] a.e.e.e.GlobalControllerExceptionHandler : Business exception occurred: Max retry attempts reached
```

I'm new to reactive programming and using webclient so any help would be appreciated thank you!!

Comment: what kind of token are you using? often you can read the expiration date from the token. Ideally you should check the expiration date and refresh the token before doing the request so you don't have to retry

Comment: oh i see your token in the logs. It's a JWT token https://jwt.io as you can see there is an `exp` property that you can read